# Help on propositional calculus problem

Tags: propositional-calculus

Prove that the statements “$(p \mathbin{\text{and}} \neg q) \mathbin{\text{implies}} q$” and “$(p \mathbin{\text{and}} \neg q) \mathbin{\text{implies}} \neg p$” are logically equivalent. What simpler statement is logically equivalent to both of them?

Comment: What tools are at your disposal?  Can you use truth tables?  Do you need to write a formal proof?

Comment: No, I have to use logical equivalences.

Comment: Which logical equivalences can you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are equivalent:

1. $p\wedge q\Rightarrow \neg q$
2. $\neg \left(p\wedge q\right)\vee\neg q$
3. $\left(\neg p\vee\neg q\right)\vee\neg q$
4. $\neg p\vee\neg q$

Starting at 1) you arrive at 4). If you start with $p\wedge q\Rightarrow \neg p$
then you will end up with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help.  Take the statement $(A\wedge B)\Rightarrow -B$.  Then to obtain your first statement let $A=p$ and $B=-q$.  Then use that $--q=q$.  For your second statement let $A=-q$ and $B=p$.  Here you need to use that $A\wedge B=B\wedge A$.

Answer (score 0):

You might assume them equivalent, then *only* using equivalences try to find a common form.  I use Reverse Polish Notation.  Thus, instead of (p$\land$q) I write pqK.  Instead of (p$\lor$q) I write pqA.  Instead of $\lnot$p, I write pN.  Instead (p$\rightarrow$q) I write pqC.  I'll also write the logical equivalence of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ as

$\alpha$ $\beta$ E

So, let's suppose

1. pqNKqC  and pqNKpNC logically equivalent or "pqNKqC pqNKpNC E".  Since pqC pqNKN E we can thus obtain 2 from 1.
2. pqNKqNKN pqNKpNNKN E.  Since ppN p E we can obtain 3.
3. pqNKqNKN pqNKpKN E.  Since pqKN pNqNA E we can obtain 4.
4. pqNKNqNNA pqNKNpNA E.  Since ppN p E we can obtain 5.
5. pqNKNqA pqNKNpNA E.  Since pqKN pNqNA E we can obtain 6.
6. pNqNNAqA pNqNNApNA E.  Since q qNN E we can obtain 7.
7. pNqAqA pNqApN E.   Since pqArA pqrAA E we can obtain 8.
8. pNqqAA pNqpNAA E.    Since pqA qpA E we can obtain 9.
9. pNqqAA pNpNqAA E.    Since pqrAA pqArA E we can obtain 10.
10. pNqqAA pNpNAqA E.   Since ppA p E we can obtain 11.
11. pNqA pNqA E.

Consequently, since we only used equivalences, and since equivalences all come as reversible when used, we could have started with 11. and derived 1 using the equivalence indicated on the right in the reverse order.  11. also contains a statement form logically equivalent to both of the original two statement forms.